# Best choices for analyzing custom log files

Tags: parsing, logging, graph

I have written a logger for my projects. I logs to text files and as you may guess there's a time-stamp, namespace, class, method... and finally a log message. Like this:

```
TestNamespace.MyProject.exe Error: 0 : 
11/11/2010 10:24:11 AM
Assembly: TestNamespace.MyProject.exe
Class: myClass
Method: Test

This is a log message !


TestNamespace.MyProject.exe Error: 0 : 
11/11/2010 10:24:12 AM
Assembly: TestNamespace.MyProject.exe
Class: myClass
Method: Test2

This is another log message !
```

I'm looking for a free tool for analyzing my log files (some tables, graphs etc).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a [`LogParser`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) which is very flexible with any log format. The down-side is, it's a command-line tool and has no changes from 2005 (version 2.2). You can write SQL commands against your log file and it will generate proper tables/charts for you. Some GUI tools are written for it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are outputting log messages in a custom format, you practically need a custom parser for it.

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
import datetime
from collections import namedtuple
Record = namedtuple( 'Record', 'file,level,number,datetime,assembly,class,method,message' )

def block_iter( theFile ):
    file_iter= iter(theFile)
    while True:
        items= [ next(file_iter) for x in range(9) ]
        if not items: break
        yield items

def record_iter( blocks ):
    for items in blocks:
        file, level, number = items[0].split(":")
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime( items[1], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p" )
        _, _, asm = items[2].partition(":")
        _, _, cls = items[3].partition(":")
        _, _, mth = items[4].partition(":")
        txt = "".join( items[5:] )
        yield Record( file, level, number, dt, asm, cls, mth, txt )

with open( "someapp.log", "r" ) as source:
    for log in record_iter( block_iter( source ) ):
        print log
```

Something like that might help get you started.